# Dart callback loses parameter value

Tags: dart

**Update**: The string I passed was null. :(

Why does the following always have an `eventName` of `null` in the callback? What can I do to fix it?

```
void listen(Node target, String eventName) {
  target.addEventListener(eventName, (Event event) =>
    print('Event "$eventName": ${stringify(event)}'));
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect it to have a different value? How do you use it?

Comment: The print function uses it. I expect it to print "Event <name>: <value>", but it always prints "Event null: value". The value of the argument `eventName` is gone. I'm just logging events while I debug some things.

Comment: What do you get if you put a print statement before `target.addEventListener(...)` like `print('EventName: "$eventName"');`?

Comment: null :(. Sorry it looks like I can't add a static const to a class marked with @JS(). Debugging that stuff is hard

Comment: It's quite limited what `@JS` supports.